# Swagger UI Authorize button does not appear

Tags: java, spring, swagger-ui

EDIT: I'm using Swagger UI 2.5.0 and attempting to configure it to use oauth authentication. From what I understand from looking at the petstore example and other pieces I've read if I include a security schema & context in my Docket it should automatically display the button - is this the case? If so what else am I missing here?

My API's appear fine in the swagger UI - it's just that the authorize button (and therefore any means of authorization) is missing

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .groupName("api")
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/api.*"))
            .build()
            .securitySchemes(newArrayList(securitySchema()))
            .securityContexts(newArrayList(securityContext()));
}


public static final String securitySchemaOAuth2 = "oauth2schema";
public static final String authorizationScopeGlobal = "global";
public static final String authorizationScopeGlobalDesc ="accessEverything";

private OAuth securitySchema() {
    AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope(authorizationScopeGlobal, authorizationScopeGlobal);
    LoginEndpoint loginEndpoint = new LoginEndpoint("http://localhost:9999/sso/login");
    GrantType grantType = new ImplicitGrant(loginEndpoint, "access_token");
    return new OAuth(securitySchemaOAuth2, newArrayList(authorizationScope), newArrayList(grantType));
}

private SecurityContext securityContext() {
    return SecurityContext.builder()
            .securityReferences(defaultAuth())
            .forPaths(PathSelectors.regex("/api.*"))
            .build();
}

private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
    AuthorizationScope authorizationScope
            = new AuthorizationScope(authorizationScopeGlobal, authorizationScopeGlobalDesc);
    AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
    authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
    return newArrayList(
            new SecurityReference(securitySchemaOAuth2, authorizationScopes));
}
```

Comment: Did you try this: @OpenAPIDefinition(security = {@SecurityRequirement(name = "bearer-key")})